# Can't sign in via Spring Security to LDAP

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

I'm trying to connect my Spring program to my Active Directory LDAP.
I can connect to the LDAP via Active Directory Explorer.
[image: Active Directory Explorer]

But I can't sign in as user **addrbook** to the LDAP via my software. Each time I get this error

[image: Sign in form]

I trying to test connection on unboundid-ldapsdk and it's ldif file. It was working ok.

My code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=test")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://192.168.10.30:389/dc=hq,dc=local")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
}
```

}

These are error logs from Spring:

```
> 08:58:58.408 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A69, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v4563 ]; remaining name 'uid=addrbook,ou=test' at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:190) at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:81)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:222)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:130)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A69, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v4563 ]; remaining name 'uid=addrbook,ou=test'
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:820)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:803)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.retrieveEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.authenticate(PasswordComparisonAuthenticator.java:76)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.doAuthentication(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:174)
.. 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090A69, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v4563 ]
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3299)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3205)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2996)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_getAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1358)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:235)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext. java:141) at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:129)
at java.naming/javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:171)
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.lambda$retrieveEntry$1(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext(LdapTemplate.java:817)
... 61 common frames omitted
```

I stuck here for a few days. Please help me

Update 1:

[image: Error]

Comment: The attribute that holds "addrbook" is cn (not uid) so you need to change the rdn accordingly : `userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=test")`.

Comment: Thank you EricLavault. I changed uid to cn, but got same error. Added screenshot above,

Comment: Any other ideas please?